# How to display IP address of all interface for a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to display all network interface for a script, including vip.

```
 ~]$ /sbin/ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:90:88:37  
          inet addr:192.168.1.15  Bcast:192.168.1.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9786341 errors:0 dropped:152 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10162602 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6846599961 (6529.4 Mb)  TX bytes:2951709145 (2814.9 Mb)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:90:E1:2E  
          inet addr:25.10.100.15  Bcast:25.10.100.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:42436 errors:0 dropped:150 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5484037 (5.2 Mb)  TX bytes:2446 (2.3 Kb)
```

Like this

```
 eth0   00:50:56:90:88:37  192.168.1.15 MTU:1500
 eth0   00:50:56:90:E1:2E  25.10.100.15 MTU:1500
```

Please help to get this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` and set the record separator to an empty line, for example this

```
/sbin/ifconfig  | awk -v RS='' '{print $14}'
```

will print

```
MTU:1500
MTU:1500
```

so just pick the fields you want.

Comment: Looking output like this ->

 `eth0   00:50:56:90:88:37  192.168.1.15 MTU:1500
 eth0   00:50:56:90:E1:2E  25.10.100.15 MTU:1500
`
or just 

<interface> <IP address> <Mask>

`eth0    192.168.1.15 
eth1    25.10.100.15
`

Comment: You will have all the fields ($1, $2, .., $NF) set, print whatever you want